# Not able to sign in or signup with email and password using firebase auth in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter firebase auth with email and password. When I am doing sign in or sign up I am getting the following error:

> An internal error has occurred. [ Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SignInWithPassword are blocked. ]

I am using firebase_auth: ^0.8.4+2. I have already enabled signup with email and password from my firebase console.

Comment: Can you include your code? and have you setup Firebase in your app correctly?

Comment: I can add the link to the project on github. But it was working before and I was able to sign in and signup with email and password.

Comment: I don't think there is any issue with setting up firebase as I did it and it was working fine. I just didn't logout of my device for a long time and now when I did, it stopped working.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache/storage of the app (if on Android) or uninstalling and reinstalling the app (if on iOS) or trying on another device like a simulator?

Comment: Yes I tried all the above and I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing this issue because my api keys were restricted. I had to go to my google developer console and change the restrictions on my api keys and allow the toolkit api. It worked for me then.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the apiKey in the environment file of Angular was allowed to only use a few Google Cloud APIs as I had restricted.

I went to [https://console.cloud.google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUpkA.png),
chose the project

`(same as the Firebase project of course)`

and then API & Services > Credentials.
There in the list of API keys, I looked for the same API key given in the project overview of Firebase, clicked on it, and went on the tab API restrictions.
Therewith the select box, I added to the list of allowed APIs the Identity Toolkit API.

or make it Don't restrict key

[image]